# KeyError due to [missing or damaged?] row in a certain column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I was doing my data analyst capstone of IBM using the csv "https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DA0321EN-SkillsNetwork/LargeData/m1_survey_data.csv". I was on my to create a new column in a data frame by iterating over the rows of the dataframe but pandas threw an error "KeyError: 1168". I was really confused so I looped over and found out that when the code is executing df.CompTotal[1168], pandas throws an error. Here's all the relevant code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DA0321EN-SkillsNetwork/LargeData/m1_survey_data.csv")
df.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)
#length of data frame is 13398 
for i in range(len(df):
    print(i)
    print(df.CompTotal[i])
```

After printing i = 1668, it throws the error KeyError: 1168(it also happens to 1169 too)
I looked into the csv file in Excel and found out that the row 1168 does exist. Any reason why this happens? df.CompTotal[2000] works just fine.
Here's the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S32rL.png)

Comment: That row got dropped when you `drop_duplicates`?

Comment: That's actually true, never tested it with other rows. How do I address this problem?

Comment: I solved it, I just need to place ignore_index = True to the parameter of drop_duplicates. Thank you so much for the help